# Is my videocard dead?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

My videocard became unusable all of the sudden. It's Nvidia Quadro M600M (low-end)
I normally use Ubuntu Linux but after having booting problems and switched to Windows
where Windows is throwing code 43 on the videocard. Windows is up-to-date
so no driver are missing and I installed latest Nvidia driver straight from Nvidia download site.

I tried to power off the computer and power cycle it (unplug power cord and hold power button for a minute).

Didn't help.

[image]
[image]

Am I correct since Ubuntu as well as Window are having problems with the videocard
I'm concluding that the videocard is dead. Am I correct ?

Comment: I see you have Driver Booster on there. Did everything work better before you ran that? It's a known system borker. Avoid like the plague.

Comment: In fact I've had the opposite experience so far. Where drivers from Windows failed me Driver Booster came to rescue successfully by far. In this case it showed that the Nvidia driver is up-to-date so I didn't need to use it.

Comment: It's possible that the video card is broken. Try it on another computer, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

It still works (at least partially) else you wouldn't have any picture.
But the NVidia specific driver crashes and Windows reverts to the basic SVGA driver.
This is usually a sign that the video-card has somehow gotten into an invalid configuration state and needs to be reset.

I recommend you shut down the computer completely and move the video-card to a different PCIe slot (if possible).
If that is not possible (only 1 slot) remove it altogether. Boot the computer without the card. Wait a minute and then shut it of again and re-insert the card.

Also: Changing video-settings in Bios/UEFI (if there are settings there) may also help to reset the card. (Especially any display RAM/Shared memory related video settings.)

Comment: Haven't got more slots so I went for removing the videocard and booting computer up without it so the default Windows basic vga driver is used. Had it on for about a minute and shut it off again. Put the videocard back but still the same thing. Code 43.

Comment: I found no videocard-related settings in BIOS.